# Utilizing the While Loop

Tags: c++

The prompt is to start with a random number and to keep replacing that number repeatedly under the conditions that (1) if the number is even, you divide it by two and (2) if the number is odd, you multiply it by three then add one.

So, for example:

If the number was 13, then the output would be: 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1

(Also the program must stop after the value of 1 is reached)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    int x;
    int lengthcount=0;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";

    cin >> x; 

    while(x%2==0)
    {
        x=x/2;
        cout << x << " ";
        lengthcount++;
    }
    while(x%2==1)
    {
        x=x*3+1;
        cout << x << " ";
        lengthcount++;
    }
    if(x==1)
    {
        return 1; 
    }

    cout << "Length:" << lengthcount << endl;
}
```

This is what I have so far. But when I compile and run the code only the first value of 40 appears. Not the rest of components. I'm assuming it has to do with the loops not connecting with one another. How do I get it so that the output of one loop would go to the other loop and back?

Comment: Step 1: Stop assuming things. Step 2: Fire up your debugger and find out what's _actually_ going on.

Comment: what you wrote is: while the number is even, divide by 2. Then while the number is odd, multiply by 3 and add 1. And that's the end! So with 13 you go past the first while, iterate once through the second, and you're done. What you need is a global while loop that runs as long as x is not 1. Within that loop you do various tests and changes to x.

Answer (score 2):

Two sequential loops *aren't* connected, and there's no way that you can or should make them so.

Instead, have a single loop, with an `if`/`else` inside it to handle the odd/even cases respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The way the code currently is, neither the division by 2^n, nor the 3n+1 operation can be performed more than once. You need to have an outer loop around these operations.

The correct way to exit a loop is with the `break` keyword, not `return`.

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    int lengthcount=0;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";

    cin >> x; 

    while(true) {
        while(x%2==0)
        {
            x=x/2;
            cout << x << " ";
            lengthcount++;
        }
        if(x==1)
        {
            break;
        }

        x=x*3+1;
        cout << x << " ";
        lengthcount++;
    }

    cout << "Length:" << lengthcount << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get it so that the output of one loop would go to the other loop and back?

You syould introduce loop in your code.

Furthermore, because `1%2==1` is true, `x==1` should always be false after `while(x%2==1)`.

An example of fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    int x;
    int lengthcount=0;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";

    cin >> x;

    for(;;)
    {
        while(x%2==0)
        {
            x=x/2;
            cout << x << " ";
            lengthcount++;
        }
        if(x==1) // check if the value of 1 is reached
        {
            break;
        }
        while(x%2==1)
        {
            x=x*3+1;
            cout << x << " ";
            lengthcount++;
        }
    }
    if(x!=1) // x should be 1 in here
    {
        return 1; 
    }

    cout << "Length:" << lengthcount << endl;
}
```